# Why doesn't my ecplise console start with StatET

Tags: eclipse, r

I just installed Eclipse with StatET, everything standard, and now my console does not seem to load when I open the StatET perspective.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Surely an error pops up? My guesses would be: no rJava installed, incorrect paths to R, incorrect java paths. What system is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also use StatEt. It has the same behaviour here. To start an R console I would have to select it from the "run-button-menu".

I think this is the normal behaviour. For example this makes sence if you tell StatEt to use the projects-path as working directory for R. Therefore you would have to select a project and start the R-console afterwards.

[edit]
BTW, do you already know those instructions: [video](http://www.walware.de/it/statet/s-console.spage), [pdf](http://www.splusbook.com/RIntro/R_Eclipse_StatET.pdf)