# How to use "R Graph Builder" and "R Graphics" view with StatEt Eclipse Plugin?

Tags: r, eclipse, ggplot2, statet

I am new to R and want to use the Eclipse plugin StatEt with Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2) on Windows 7.

I tried to create an example plot with the R Graph Builder. I click the "play button" and get following output on the `R Code` tab. Furthermore, I hear a "ping" sound.

```
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = cyl))
p <- p + labs(title = "test")

print(p)
```

However, I can not see any graph.

=> Is the purpose of the "play action" only to produce the console output?

[image]

=> Where can I find documentation about the Graph Builder?

=> What data can I enter to get a first example graph?

Furthermore, when I plot a graph in StatEt, I would expect its output to be in the view "R Graphics". However, a new window is opened by R. I have the option "Set R Graphic view by StatET as default graphic device for new plots in R" enabled on the tab "R Console" in my console run configuration.

=> What is the purpose of the "R Graphics" view?

Example plots:

```
x<-c(1:10)
y<-sin(x)       
plot(x=x,y=y)
```

-

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = mtcars,aes(x=wt))+geom_bar()
```

Related questions:

- [How does one install 'rj' in StatET plugin for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727822/how-does-one-install-rj-in-statet-plugin-for-eclipse)
- [ClassNotFoundException for StatEt Eclipse plugin / RJ. Compatibility issue with Java9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48096198/classnotfoundexception-for-statet-eclipse-plugin-rj-compatibility-issue-with)
- [Why doesn't my ecplise console start with StatET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124950/why-doesnt-my-ecplise-console-start-with-statet)
- [How to index R library for Help view of StatEt Eclipse plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47941228/how-to-index-r-library-for-help-view-of-statet-eclipse-plugin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In order to use those features of StatEt you need to select `RJ (default)` instead of `Rterm` in the Console run configuration. (`Rterm` might be useful for trouble shooting and initial setup but `RJ` is required for normal usage. The R package `RJ` needs to be installed from within R. Apply Rterm once for doing so or use R.exe directly. Also see [ClassNotFoundException for StatEt Eclipse plugin / RJ. Compatibility issue with Java9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48096198/classnotfoundexception-for-statet-eclipse-plugin-rj-compatibility-issue-with))
- `RJ 2.1` is not compatible to `Java 9`. Currently you need to install Java8 and select it in the JRE settings of the run configuration.
- Make sure that the box `Set R Graphic view by StatET as default graphic device for new plots in R` is checked in Run configuration>R console. (It is checked by default.)

[image]

Once you have created your graph, the example code is written in code. This is normally sent to the R console. You should now be able to see the graphical result in the R Graphics view.

[image]

Comment: I have the option enabled and tried your input settings. The output to the "R Console" tab (marked red in your screenshot) works. However, I can't see some output in the extra console view (green font in your example) nor can I see the graphical output in the "R Graphics" view. Instead I hear the ping - (Error sound?). Maybe the graphical output does not work on Windows. Do you use a Linux OS?

Comment: From what I remember you had trouble to install the rJ dependency no ? I think it might be linked. Have you managed to make it work ?

Comment: I did not manage to use RJ yet. I'll try again. Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727822/how-does-one-install-rj-in-statet-plugin-for-eclipse

Comment: I'm willing to help you there. I'll post a comment on your rj question

Comment: I created a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48096198/classnotfoundexception-for-statet-eclipse-plugin-rj-compatibility-issue-with